# Getting "Failed to initialize temporary dir" in Dovecot when doing MOVE to Spam via IMAP

Tags: centos, email-server, dovecot

The IMAP client attempts to move emails in Spam folder. Sometimes (very rarely) this operation fails as below:

```
> TAG4 UID MOVE 32235,32234 "Spam"
< TAG4 NO [CANNOT] Failed to initialize temporary dir
```

Usually, this operation succeeds (the same account, the same client, etc). The IMAP server is Dovecot 2.2 on CentOS 7.1 64-bit, I believe. Dovecot logs don't have any errors for the timeframe of this error. Account quota is not exceeded. Next attempt to move the same messages to spam succeeds. I also noticed that all the time it occurs when I select more than one message. I've never seen this error with a single message.

Googling reveals this error message in Dovecot sources and nowhere else:
http://code.metager.de/source/xref/dovecot/plugin/antispam/src/mailtrain.c

What could be the reason of this error?